# List files that do not contain pattern

Tags: linux, bash, file, grep, pattern-matching

In bash, how to list files that do NOT contain a given string?

---

Given that

```
grep --include=*.c  -rlw './' -e "pattern"
```

return any file that matches the pattern I was expecting that

```
grep --include=*.c  -rlwv './' -e "pattern"
```

would return any file that does not match the pattern but it just returns all the `*.c` files regardless of wether they match the pattern.

Comment: This command is working fine for me

Comment: `-v` means to match lines that don't contain the pattern. So your command will list any files that contain a line that doesn't match the pattern. It doesn't mean that **no** lines match the pattern.

Comment: The only files that would be excluded from the result would be ones where **all** lines match the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use -L option:

```
grep  -L -r -i --include \*.c "pattern" ./
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -v option also

```
grep -v -rwl "pattern"
```